# Improve speed of nested loop

Tags: python

I am trying to improve the speed of my python code. It takes a long time to execute for large dataset. Is there a better way to do it at a faster speed?

```
for i in range(0,len(nodes)):
fragment = nodes[i]
for l in range(0, length1):
    fragment1 = Text[l:int(l)+int(k)]      
    count = [0]*gen_len

    for j in range( 0, gen_len ):  
        if fragment[j] != fragment1[j]:
            count[j] = count[j]+1            

        if j == (gen_len-1):

            if int(sum(count)) <= int(Num_mismatches):
                count2[i] = count2[i]+1
                result2[i] = fragment
                result.append(fragment)

                if count2[i] > maxval:
                    maxval = count2[i]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: You could consider using `pypy` if you don't have dependencies on C extensions or `scipy`.

Comment: Is this python2.x?  If yes, you might see a decent speedup if you turn the nested `range(0, ...)` to `xrange(0, ...)` to avoid creating a whole bunch of throw-away lists.

Comment: This won't be much of a speedup, but your code under `if j == (gen_len-1):` can be placed in an [else-clause of the containing for-loop](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html).

Comment: for `fragment1 = Text[l:int(l)+int(k)] ` is better to pop the first letter and put the new one at the end

Comment: Thank you everyone. I am new to python and I appreciate all your suggestions. I'll try them. Thanks!

Comment: This question may be on-topic for Code Review, but it doesn't meet Code Review's quality standards and is thus unsuitable for migration in its current state. The indentation is incorrect, making it broken code. Also, the purpose of the code needs to be clarified (and stated in the title; see [How to Ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 1):

If using Python 3 replace `izip` with `zip` and `xrange` with `range`.

```
from itertools import islice, izip

for i in xrange(0,len(nodes)):
    fragment = nodes[i]
    for l in xrange(0, length1): 
        # fragment1 was replaced by islice to avoid list creation
        # It may or may not be faster.  Try timing a version
        # where you replace islice(Text, 1, l+k) with Text[l:int(l)+int(k)]   
        count = sum(f != f1 for f, f1 in izip(fragement, islice(Text, 1, l+k)))
        if count <= Num_mismatches:
            count2[i] += 1
            # code smell:  why have both result and result2?
            result2[i] = fragment
            result.append(fragment)
            # you are not using maxval anywhere in these loops.
            # you may want to set it after these loops.
            if count2[i] > maxval:
                maxval = count2[i]
```

There were a number of places where you were casting to `int`.  I removed those because it looks like they are already `int` (`Num_mismatches`, `l`, `k`).

Comment: Thank you everyone. I am new to python and I appreciate all your suggestions. I'll try them. Thanks!